# AD Gallery. ul with two lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I have a problem with plugin AD Gallery for jQuery. When i have a lot of thumbs below the big picture, it's ok, (example - http://triavto.geosurf.ru/cars/chevrolet/aveo_3d/), but when there are only three thumbs I have strange bug with two-lines  because of its too small width (example http://triavto.geosurf.ru/cars/ford/mondeo/). I did everything from manual, but I don't know why this plugin calculates so strange width in second example...

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying the code to below helped me to resolve the issue for 3 thumbnails

```
var inter = setInterval(

 function () {
  if (thumb_count == thumbs_loaded) {
  var list = context.nav.find('.ad-thumb-list');
  list.css('width', thumb_wrapper_width + 'px');
  clearInterval(inter);
 };
}, 100);
```